# Python Shape Printing

Tags: python

[image: shape] Hi everyone, I have an assignment to acquire this shape in Python. I am a beginner, I tried to use nested loops to create this shape but I couldn't. Could someone help? Thanks a lot. (I couldn't copy the output exactly I'm sorry)

I used nested for loops, if and else statements in various ways (for example, I've tried to write stars at the end of a row) but I couldn't get the shape. I am editing the post in order to show you my effort. I am really sorry that my output is really different from the wanted one.

```
len = int(input("enter an odd number: "))
if len % 2 == 0:
    print("enter an odd number")

else:
    row = int((len+1) / 2)
    for i in range (0,len):
        print("#",end="")
    print()

    for i in range(0,row):
        print("*")
        print("*", end=" ")
        for j in range(1,len):
            print("*",end="")

    for i in range(0,len):
        print("#",end="")
```

for n = 5

```
#####
*  *
*  *
*  *
 * * 
 * * 
*  *
#####
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - it's OK to be stuck, or ask very basic questions. But it's expected you share what you tried, and explain where you're stuck exactly, so people can help you with your problem, instead of doing your work for you. Have a look at [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). People are downvoting your question because it's not clear that you made an effort, and you didn't share your code.

Comment: The top and bottom row will be handled separately.  The interior rows are all the same format: some number of spaces, a star, some number of spaces, and a star.  It's just a matter of figuring out the number of spaces, and that you can derive from the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one way of solving it:

- if we define *n* as the sample input, the shape can be divided into 3 steps of length *(n//2)* each.
- Initialization: `print('#'*n)`
- Step 1: `for i in range(n//2):   print('*'+' '*(n-2)+'*')`
- Step 2a: create a print_list: `print_list = [k*' ' + '*'+ (n-2-2*k)*' ' + '*' + k*' ' for k in range(n//2)]`
- Step 2b: Now print each line in print_list
- Step 3: Then print each line in print_list[::-1]
- End: `print('#'*n)`

Implemented Code:

```
n = int(input("enter an odd number: ")) 
if n % 2 == 0: 
    print("enter an odd number") 
else: 
    print("#"*n) 
    for i in range(n//2): 
       print('*'+' '*(n-2)+'*')  
       print_list = [k * ' ' + '*' + (n - 2 - 2*k) * ' ' + '*' + k * ' 'for k in range(n//2)]  
       for p in print_list: print(p)
       for p in print_list[::-1]: print(p)

       print("#"*n)
```

Comment: Hello, I am having an error at step 1, it says "expected type int, got str instead". I am trying to implement it the way as you described

Comment: Step 1 was missing a parentheses

Comment: I cannot put my code into comments to show what I've done. I'm putting it down as an answer. Thanks for your suggestions. I've tried to implement my code properly but I guess I've done mistakes again. It would be very good if you can check my code again. Thanks sir

Comment: The implemented code is in the edited comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But in output the right-hand side is not curving. How can we get rid of this?

Comment: Can you show what output you are getting?

Comment: I am sending it to my answer below

Comment: Check the new version of the code above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. God bless you. The code is working perfectly and in addition it is printing the pattern more than one but I think it is not a big deal. I am going to examine the code in order to understand the logic. Thank you so much again.